Who has a winning strategy?
Rhian and Jack are playing a game in which initially the number $10^6$ is written on a blackboard. If the current number on the board is $n$, a move consists of choosing two different positive integers $a$, $b$ such that $n = ab$ and replacing $n$ with $|a-b|$. Rhian starts, then the players make moves alternately. A player loses if they are unable to move.
Determine, with proof, which player has a winning strategy.
Initial thoughts:
It is easy to see the games ends at $1$, as for any $n>1$, $n$ can be factorized as $n\cdot 1$, and so it would be replaced by $|n-1|$.
I will refer to $n=1$ as a loss, as by definition the player loses, and a move that leads to a losing position or a loss as a winning one, and a move that leads to a winning position as a losing one.
For $n=1$, it is a loss.
For $n=2$, $n$ can only be factorised as $2\cdot 1$, leading to a loss. So it is a winning position.
For $n=3$, $n$ can only be factorised as $3\cdot 1$, leading to a winning position. So it is a losing position.
For $n=4$, $n$ can only be factorised as $4\cdot 1$, leading to a losing position. So it is a winning position.
For $n=5$, $n$ can only be factorised as $5\cdot 1$, leading to a winning position, so it is a losing one.
For $n=6$, $n$ can be factorised as $6\cdot 1$ or $3\cdot 2$. This leads to a losing position and a loss. So it is a winning one.
I think that for all even $n$, it is a winning position, and for all odd $n$, it is a losing one. So Rhian has a winning strategy. I'm not sure if this is correct, and how to prove it. (Maybe by induction?)
Any help is appreciated :)

Just a guess, but if one player always switches n to an odd number, eventually, the other player will be left with 1?

The logic you start with looks good.  Stick with it and follow the suggestion of @LucienJaccon

Don't overcomplicate things! You only need to think about parity. Everything you need is already written down here (hint: you don't need any more case analysis)

If n is odd, then the next number must be even, if n is even, then the next number can be odd, and may be even if n congruent to 0 (mod 4)?

If $n$ is odd, a valid play must have both $a$ and $b$ being odd, since an odd number cannot be the product of two even numbers, or the product of an odd number and an even number - this makes the absolute value of their difference even. If $n$ is even, we can always pick $a=n, b=1$ to make the absolute value of their difference odd.
We can also observe the game ends when $n=1$. For any other positive integer $n$, playing $a=n$, $b=1$ is a valid move. We can further observe that $n$ must decrease with every move, and cannot reach $0$.
Rhian starts from $n=1000000$. They should make any play to make the next $n$ odd. Their opponent's next play must  yield an even $n$. Rhian can continue this until eventually $n=1$, at which point their opponent has no legal moves, and they win. One simple instantiation of this strategy is for Rhian to always play $a=n$, $b=1$.
